# Optimization of branch in while loop, why less instruction cost more running time?

Tags: c, optimization, data-structures

I have one project of data structure implement by C, it exporting sorts of APIs for other program. Recently I would like to do some optimization on Hot function profiled by grofile. Here is the project for your reference.

https://github.com/Incarnation-p-lee/libds
There is one hot function binary_search_tree_node_insert, as below:

```
/*
 * RETURN the pointer of inserted node of the binary search tree
 *        If root is NULL or node is NULL, RETURN NULL.
 */
struct binary_search_tree *
binary_search_tree_node_insert(struct binary_search_tree *root,
    struct binary_search_tree *node)
{
    register struct binary_search_tree **iter;

    if (!node || !root) {
        pr_log_warn("Attempt to access NULL pointer.\n");
    } else {
        iter = &root;
        while (*iter) {
            if (node->chain.nice == (*iter)->chain.nice) {
                if (*iter == node) {
                    pr_log_info("Insert node exist, nothing will be done.\n");
                } else {
                    doubly_linked_list_merge((*iter)->chain.link, node->chain.link);
                }
                return *iter;
#ifndef OPT_HOT
            } else if (node->chain.nice > (*iter)->chain.nice) {
                    iter = &(*iter)->right;
            } else if (node->chain.nice < (*iter)->chain.nice) {
                    iter = &(*iter)->left;
#else
            } else {
                binary_search_tree_insert_path_go_through(node, iter);
#endif
            }
        }
        return *iter = node;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

I want to optimization the two else-if part as it's half-to-half branch, which may impact on pipeline a lot. So I write one macro binary_search_tree_insert_path_go_through replace these two branch. And the implementation as follow:

```
/*
 * 1. node->nice => rbx, *iter => rcx.
 * 2. compare rbx, and 0x8(rcx).
 * 3. update iter.
 */
#define binary_search_tree_insert_path_go_through(node, iter) \
    asm volatile (                                            \
        "mov $0x18, %%rax\n\t"                                \
        "mov $0x20, %%rdx\n\t"                                \
        "mov 0x8(%1), %%rbx\n\t"                              \
        "mov (%0), %%rcx\n\t"                                 \
        "cmp 0x8(%%rcx), %%rbx\n\t"                           \
        "cmovg %%rdx, %%rax\n\t"                              \
        "lea (%%rcx, %%rax), %0\n\t"                          \
        :"+r"(iter)                                           \
        :"r"(node)                                            \
        :"rax", "rbx", "rcx", "rdx")
```

But the unit test of this function has dropped about 6-8% about this change. From the objdump code(optimized code on right hand), it has less instructions, I can hardly understand why it cost more time before optimization.

[image]

And there are some details for you reference:

```
struct collision_chain {
    struct doubly_linked_list *link;
    sint64                    nice;
};
/*
 * binary search tree
 */
struct binary_search_tree {
    struct collision_chain chain;
    sint32                 height;  /* reserved for avl */
    /* root node has height 0, NULL node has height -1 */
    union {
        struct binary_search_tree *left;
        struct avl_tree           *avl_left;    /* reserved for avl   */
        struct splay_tree         *splay_left;  /* reserved for splay */
    };
    union {
        struct binary_search_tree *right;
        struct avl_tree           *avl_right;    /* reserved for avl   */
        struct splay_tree         *splay_right;  /* reserved for splay */
    };
};
struct doubly_linked_list {
    uint32                    sid;
    void                      *val;
    struct doubly_linked_list *next;
    struct doubly_linked_list *previous;
};
```

It runs on virtual-box with 2 core of i5-3xxM, and cpuinfo as following:

```
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 58
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3230M CPU @ 2.60GHz
stepping        : 9
microcode       : 0x19
cpu MHz         : 2568.658
cache size      : 6144 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 2
core id         : 0
cpu cores       : 2
apicid          : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 5
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl pni ssse3 lahf_lm
bogomips        : 5137.31
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor       : 1
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 58
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3230M CPU @ 2.60GHz
stepping        : 9
microcode       : 0x19
cpu MHz         : 2568.658
cache size      : 6144 KB
physical id     : 0
siblings        : 2
core id         : 1
cpu cores       : 2
apicid          : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fpu             : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level     : 5
wp              : yes
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl pni ssse3 lahf_lm
bogomips        : 5137.31
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 36 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: In x86_64 64-bits lfs machine, Linux pli.lfs 3.10.10 #1 SMP Sun Mar 2 18:07:33 CST 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux.

Comment: Can you give more processor specifics: `cat /proc/cpuinfo`?

Comment: less instructions doesn't mean that it'll run faster. If you use -O3 the code may very well be longer than lower levels of optimizations. Even a snippet with 1 or 2 instructions that form an infinite or very long loop will run longer than a program with more instructions but less loop

Comment: The assembly compare code are compiled with -O3 under gcc.

Comment: Update cpuinfo for your reference.

Comment: What is the type of `nice` here, and what is the possible range of values for this variable?

Comment: Miss structure collision_chain, updated already.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's the same for modern processors, but [Linus really didn't like the CMOV instruction back in '07](http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/cmov.html).

Since you are micro-optimizing, move the equality check to the last position. It's almost always false, yet you're making it in every iteration.

Moreover, I'd try *not* using the pointer-to-pointer pattern. Indirection tends to make optimizers choke due to pointer aliasing concerns. Instead, use an inch-worm pattern with two pointers:

```
void insert(NODE *x, NODE **root) {
  NODE *trail = NULL;
  NODE *lead = *root;
  while (lead) {
    trail = lead;
    if (x->key < lead->key)
      lead = lead->left;
    else if (x->key > lead->key)
      lead = lead->right;
    else return; // do nothing;
  }
  // lead has found null, so insert
  if (trail)
    // redo the last key comparison
    if (x->key < trail->key)
      trail->left = x;
    else
      trail->right = x;
  else 
    *root = x;
}
```

On my MacBook, this compiles to the following 64-bit code, where the loop includes only 10 instructions. It's hard to tell from the tiny listings in your post, but it looks like it's is considerably longer:

```
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movq    (%rsi), %rdx
    testq   %rdx, %rdx
    je      LBB0_11
    movl    16(%rdi), %ecx
LBB0_2:                                 
    movq    %rdx, %rax     # dx=lead, ax=trail
    cmpl    16(%rax), %ecx # comparison with key
    jge     LBB0_4         # first branch
    movq    %rax, %rdx     # go left (redundant because offset(left)==0!)
    jmp     LBB0_6
LBB0_4:                                 
    jle     LBB0_12        # second branch
    leaq    8(%rax), %rdx  # go right
LBB0_6:                                 
    movq    (%rdx), %rdx   # move lead down the tree
    testq   %rdx, %rdx     # test for null
    jne     LBB0_2         # loop if not
    testq   %rax, %rax     # insertion logic
    je      LBB0_11
    movl    16(%rdi), %ecx
    cmpl    16(%rax), %ecx
    jge     LBB0_10
    movq    %rdi, (%rax)
    popq    %rbp
    retq
LBB0_11:
    movq    %rdi, (%rsi)
LBB0_12:                   # return for equal keys
    popq    %rbp
    retq
LBB0_10:
    movq    %rdi, 8(%rax)
    popq    %rbp
    retq
```

If comparisons are expensive, (you don't show what "nice" is), you could also experiment with storing the binary result of the trail comparison so that the final check uses this rather than redoing the comparison.

Comment: I'm a student in university and just finished my assembly course this previous quarter (we used SPARC, though). There's a lot of content in this answer that I'd love to understand better. I'll start with this: could you elaborate on the "inch-worm" pattern as opposed to pointer-to-pointer? How does that affect compilation?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Put equal compare to last position may impact performance a little, but I think the inline asm discard the cmp and jmp instructions, it may be faster than if-else.

Comment: Or in other hand, should I rewrite all the code under while loop for optimization.

Comment: @IncarnationP.Lee You didn't ready Linux Tovalds article on CMOV?  It can be a very expensive instruction and slower then branching. The kind of branching in this loop is precisely the kind that multiple execution unit CPUs are designed to perform well on. They more-or-less execute both sides of the branch in parallel, then throw away one computation when the comparison is complete, so there is now pipeline flush at all.

Comment: actually I often see Intel compiler emit `cmov`s instead of jumps or set flags like gcc and clang, so those conditional moves may be much better now

Comment: I need to check that cmov cost 10 cycles ? There is one doc of intel for cycles of all instruction in my working computer. I'd like to verify it.

Comment: @Gene To left or right is half-to-half if-else(unpredictable), so it should be a good win for cmov from that mail list. For predictable situation, such as 90% taken, 10% not taken, cmov is one bad thing.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but you can avoid the `else if` altogether:

```
sint64 mask,left,right;
...
if (node->chain.nice == (*iter)->chain.nice)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    mask  = ((*iter)->chain.nice - node->chain.nice) >> 63;
    left  = (sint64)(&(*iter)->left);
    right = (sint64)(&(*iter)->right);
    iter  = (struct binary_search_tree**)((left & mask) | (right & ~mask));
}
```

Comment: Nice advice, I will have a try.

Comment: If you want to do these tricks, just put the child pointers in an array where children[0] is left and children[1] is right, then say node = node->children[x->key > node->key].

Comment: @Gene: That was my initial idea, but you end up having to: 1. Store them into the array at every iteration (as they are different every time). 2. Use the sign bit as an index to the array, which is essentially equivalent to my "trick", since you still need to apply the `>>` and the `&` in order to retrieve that bit... So bottom line, I've figured that due to the first reason mentioned above, it is better off that way (i.e., my way). Thanks.

Comment: @IncarnationP.Lee: You're welcome. Please note that if the expression `(*iter)->chain.nice - node->chain.nice` itself overflows, then it might not work as expected. I haven't fully investigated that, and I'm not even sure it is an issue to begin with. But if it is, then you might be able to solve it using the Overflow Flag bit, which to the best of my knowledge is specific to your HW architecture (i.e., outside the scope of the C language standard).

Comment: I do not think put it to children[0] is a good idea, because it need two instruction for echo iteration.

Comment: @barakmanos This avoiding if-else seems a little slower than raw version.

Comment: @IncarnationP.Lee: 1. I suppose that it is architecture-dependent (i.e. some architectures might be optimized for branching operations, others might be optimized for bit-wise operations). 2. When it comes to branching, it is really hard to predict sometimes, as it depends on caching heuristics and so forth. One thing for sure - with branching, your running time becomes non-constant over different executions, thus it is harder to predict your **worst-case** performance, which is sometimes critical (mostly in RT applications). 3. As I stated to begin with, it is merely a suggestion to consider.

Comment: @barakmanos Yes, there are lots of things may effect on runtime execution, Thanks for you help. :). I prefer the pointer and type cast may take some time for avoiding version. Anyway, optimization always has the result out of your control...

Comment: @IncarnationP.Lee: You're welcome. This optimization in fact puts things "back into your control", since the non-constant running time of your `else/if` statement is replaced for a constant-running time of my bit-wise operations (although they might yield worse running-time average). As mentioned on previous comments here, you can use `children[2]` instead of `left` and `right`, change `sint64 mask` to `uint64 index`, and obtain `iter` from `chlidren[index]`, though I doubt that it would yield any difference from what I have suggested in my original answer. Thanks.